# How to prevent execution of PHP script file in an asp.net web application

Tags: php, asp.net

I have an asp.net web application. Due to security issue, I need to prevent execution of PHP script that may be uploaded to my host. Is it possible that hackers use this PHP files to crash my servers?
Consider that the hackers can find out the virtual path of uploaded file and they can use url to access uploaded file and then execute php file.

How can I prevent this issue.

Comment: Upload to a path that is not accessible directly to a request?

Comment: Am I very wrong if I suggest not running a php server on your asp.net server?

Comment: If URL of access files is served from IIS via you web app, you can go and have a drink, it the URL of access of files has as root a php website you are dead and buried. So test it out yourself, assuming that someone can upload a php file on you filsystem upload one and access it

Comment: I use a shared host and can not upload to a path that  is not accessible directly to a request. I upload a php file and request it and it is accesseable and executable.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to prevent execution of PHP script that may be uploaded to my
>   host

Generally speaking, that's as simple as **not running things your visitors upload.** there simply shouldn't be an *opportunity,* PHP or otherwise, for a user uploaded file to be executed.

*If I had to guess,* you'r issue stems from taking user-uploaded files and stuffing them in a folder in your document root. When you serve them later, IIS is treating the like regular "site files" and passing them through their associated handlers.

**One way to handle this** is simply to put a restriction the file types a user can upload. Create a white-list:

```
*.png
*.jpeg
*.jpg
*.gif

etc.
```

In the event that a user uploads something *other* than what's on your whitelist, either reject the file or rename and/or ZIP it on the server.

**Another way to handle this**, and probably the better way, is to put the files outside the document root, either in a database or a folder *above* the root. Then, ferry them in and out with a custom handler.

If you choose a folder to stuff downloads in, you *should* be able to register a  handler for all files in a directory (untested) in your config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="path/to/downloads/*" 
        type="YourHanlderClassName, YourHandlerAssemblyName" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This should also work on file *within* the document root, as may be necessary in a shared hosting situation without database access; but it's not ideal. Typos and other configuration mistakes could allow some content in the folder available for direct access.

**If you don't care about access control**, you could conceivably also stuff a `Web.config` in your uploads/downloads folder with a generic MIME type:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".*" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But, I haven't tested that scenario *at all*. And it doesn't allow for elegant access control. So, you'll definitely need to play with it ...

Comment: The white list is good. But because of using wide range of uploaded files type and too many fileupload control in my project, I can not use that. also i has a shared host and can not save to folders outside of the root, however that's a good point. Thank you